# Symfony fragments sometime return 403 to Varnish

Tags: symfony, varnish, esi

A Symfony 2.3 app is on a web server with nginx over port 80. Varnish4 is running on a front-end server on port 80 with Nginx on port 443 as an SSL terminator. This is also tested with Varnish3 with the same results. Mostly this works very well!

After a few minutes some of the ESIs return a 403 Forbidden error with full Symfony template. I believe this is happening when cached fragments expire.

I can force the issue by:

1. Restarting Varnish to clear the cache
2. Loading a page over HTTP (all OK)
3. Loading the page over HTTPS (all OK)
4. Waiting for some ESIs to expire from cache
5. Loading the page over HTTPS (error happens here)
6. Loading the page over HTTP (all OK)

I can also force the issue by doing step 2 over HTTPS and step 5 over HTTP.

**Therefore I believe the issue is related to the ESI protocol not matching the original page's protocol. Has anyone come across this problem before, or can help diagnose/fix?**

Trusted proxies is the #1 culprit for 403 forbidden errors, but I have added `127.0.0.1` and the IP address of the front-end server to my trusted proxies list in `app/config/config.yml`. I can confirm things get far worse if I remove the trusted proxies list.

Comment: We've side-stepped the issue by forcing one protocol (and redirecting all other requests) but it's not ideal